# Prevent anchor tag from inheriting CSS styles

Tags: css, styles, anchor, stylesheet, inheritance

I'm creating a set of anchor tags in a LI dynamically in a DIV. But I see that all these anchor tags are inheriting it's styles from the default anchor tags that are in the parent DIV. Can any one please tell me how to prevent these anchor tags from inheriting it's style from the default anchor tag? Thanks.

Comment: Without code all I can say is find the initial declaration for your default anchor tags, and set it to `div > a { // code here }` This uses the direct child `>` selector which means it will only select `a` tags that are children of `div`, not `li`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem maybe something to do with inheritance. I'd suggest the following to try:

1. Reference these anchors with greater detail:

   div ul li a.class_name

   div ul li a#id_name
2. Apply styles only to that level using the > selector:

   li > a

> in this situation means only apply it to anchor which are direct children of the list element.

Is the style rules within the same stylesheet?